# Laravel, js in webpack.mix, function not found

Tags: javascript, laravel-5, webpack, laravel-blade

I'm using Laravel 5.6. In webpack.mix.js I have this:

```
.js([
    'resources/assets/js/backend/before.js',
    'resources/assets/js/backend/app.js',
    'resources/assets/js/backend/after.js',
    'resources/assets/js/backend/funcionesJquery.js',//THIS IS NEW
    'resources/assets/js/backend/events.js',
], 'public/js/backend.js')
```

Ok, now functioncesJquery.js is only this:

```
alert("LOADEAD");
function testAlert(){
    alert("TEST");
}
```

Now in a view I have this:

```
@push('after-scripts')
<script>
    testAlert();
</script>
@endpush
```

When I load the page with that view, it shows the `alert("LOADEAD");` but I'm getting a function not found anyway with `testAlert()`. Why is happening that? the code is well loaded but why it doesn't find the function.

Answer (score 0):

Because function not working without a call. You can try it. Thanks

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(document).on("keydown", disableF5);
    var testAlert='';
    if(testAlert==''){
        testAlert();
    }
});
function testAlert(){
    alert("IS NULL");
}
```